# memset causes "vector iterators incompatible" error

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, memset

Currently working on my DirectX game and using memset(0) (or ZeroMemory macro in VS if you wish) in constant buffers constructors to initialize all values with zeros and it works just fine. Problem occurs when I accidentally tried to initialize some other stuct that contains a vector this way. According to compiler (VS2010/VS2012) this causes "vector iterators incompatible", std::vector::end to be more precise. I can understand that memset might invalidate vectors iterators, but why "end" iterator is not working properly after I push back elements to the vector. Shouldn't it reposition vectors end iterator to right position (after last element)? Are all kind of std::some_container::end iterators affected by this aswell?

```
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { 
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
    }
    ~MyClass() {}
    std::vector<int>& GetData() { return m_data; }
    float            m_range;
private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;

};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.GetData().push_back(1);
    myClass.GetData().push_back(2);

    for (auto it = myClass.GetData().begin(); it != myClass.GetData().end(); it++)     
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Just... don't... use... memset. It... just works...

Comment: Well don't use `memset` problem solved. It ain't rocket science.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish doing a memset on `*this` in the constructor?? that's horrendous.

Comment: `memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));`   wtf?

Comment: `memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));` is a weapon of mass destruction.

Comment: @Ben, the only thing it doesn't do though is zeroing out the vector content...

Comment: No, it kills the vector in a bad way...

Answer (score 7):

`std::vector`  already has a default constructor that initializes the vector properly. Doing nothing has the behaviour you want. Using `memset` just has undefined behaviour.

If you want to initialize the `float` member to zero, C++ provides for that with code like the following:

```
MyClass() : m_range(0) {}
```

C++11 also allows writing `float m_range = 0;`, but Microsoft's compiler does not implement this feature yet.

The `mem*` functions are very crude tools that have no place among C++ constructs like `std::vector`. Alternatives like proper initialization, `std::copy`, and `std::fill` are superior solutions because they don't trample the type system.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be `memset`ing any objects of classes with constructors.

Comment: You should not use `memset` at all in C++.

Comment: @Zoidberg it has it's uses; but this certainly isn't one.

Comment: @Zoidberg but you can't :). Just look into your standard library header files.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : range{} { 

    }

    float range;
    std::vector<int> data;
};
```

Never use `memset`, and certainly absolutely not on `this` oh God.

Pro tip: [buy a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: It has, the `float` will be left uninitialized otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is constructed before the memset which causes problems.

Initialising an object this way is not a good approach in C++